# UISegmentedControl`` crash Xcode on Navigation Item

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol, uinavigationitem

I am Trying to put `UISegmentedControl` on the`Navigation Item`  but it crash my xcode .. I simply added the `UISegmentedControl` in the Interface Builder file(IB) file and then in `viewDisAppear`

**.h**

```
 IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
```

**.m**

```
 self.navigationItem.titleView=segmentedControl;
```

this simply crash my xcode with the error

```
2013-03-12 17:38:56.343 Magazine[4728:1dc03] *** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationBar layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UIView.m:5776
2013-03-12 17:38:56.344 Magazine[4728:1dc03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UINavigationBar's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2854012 0x1ee9e7e 0x2853e78 0x197ff35 0xe819ef 0x1efd6b0 0x7d1fc0 0x7c633c 0x7c6150 0x7440bc 0x745227 0x7458e2 0x281cafe 0x281ca3d 0x27fa7c2 0x27f9f44 0x27f9e1b 0x2d1c7e3 0x2d1c668 0xe3165c 0x2de5 0x2ce5)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

why this error is coming

Comment: Where are you putting the segmented control in Interface Builder? Couldn't you make the segmented control the title view directly in the nib file?

Comment: normally on the view... but how to make the segmented control the title view directly in the nib file

Comment: Why are u putting the Segment in the XIB and then giving in the Code as well?instead, u may alloc init the segmentedControl via code and then try..

Comment: Remove your segmented control from IB and add manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UISegmentedControl * seg1 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
    initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"von mir", @"alle", nil]];
[seg1 setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = seg1;
```